# Echo previous and next number with decimal

Tags: php, sql, html, mysqli

I am building a manga page with PHP.
My chapter rows in SQL have

```
 id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 catid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 listcatid varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 topicid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 admin_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 author varchar(255) default '',
 sourceid mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
 addtime int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 edittime int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 status tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
 publtime int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 exptime int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 archive tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 title varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 alias varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 chapter float default '0',
```

I try to show a Next Chapter and Previous Chapter each detailed chapter.
But the chapter not step by step.

In example, I want if visitor watch at chapter 10 and in Database have chapter 9, 9.5, 10.5, 10. They can be echo as Previous Chapter and Next Chapter.

If I am watching chapter 10 and use "SELECT chapter WHERE chapter= chapter+1" as the Next Chapter, the next chapter will be 11. They skiped the chapter with decimal, in my example is 10.5.

This is a demo link
http://truyentranhtuan.com/onepunch-man-chuong-48-5/

You can see the left and right arrow. I just want to echo a result like that.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I dont know how to explain my question. Can you please give me some advise @GordonLinoff  ?

Comment: We may appriciate a sample of your PHP code doing the stuff you've tried, and we have no idea of what is your chapter problem, it is often better if you explain a use case, like "the user is on the page 40.1, he reads it, at the bottom, there is a button `next chapter` that must send the user to page 40.2. Here is the actual code when I click on `next chapter`, and it sends to chapter 41.1 instead of chapter 40.2"

Comment: @KennyNguyen: Try `ROUND` .. its a mathematical function .. more info here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: @Random Thank you ! You got my problem. But I dont know hos to make it work.

Comment: Based on the DDL `chapter` is a  `varchar(255)`, what's the actual data? Is a chapter `2.1.1`  also possible?

Comment: @dnoeth Sorry for my mistake ! My new version have chapter is float.

Comment: @KennyNguyen Ok, so please add those details in your question by editing it. It may help some other users having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the next chapter which is greater than the current (current chapter = 20):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE chapter > 20 ORDER BY chapter ASC LIMIT 1;
```

And then do the reverse to get the previous chapter:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE chapter < 20 ORDER BY chapter DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Wow ! Too simple. Why I dont even think about this.

Comment: @Random, it works on varchar, int, float, and decimal. But varchar might work differently depending on table collation.

Comment: @NiklasBrunberg I deleted my comment since OP said the collumn is actually a float. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @NiklasBrunberg As far as I know, VARCHAR ordering may have strange ordering, I think it orders things like 1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... which is not the expected order...

Comment: You're right about that. @KennyNguyen should probably change from Float to Decimal as well to avoid precision errors which might occur when saving Float numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much, @NiklasBrunberg and Random. I will try both float and Decimal to unserstand it clearly. I am not good in mySQL and PHP. So I will try all method to find out the most compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the DDL `chapter` is a `varchar(255)`, so the the order will be: 
1,10,2,20,3, etc. You need to apply a typecast (or better change the column definition to a `decimal`).

Edit: Now `chapter` is a `float`, no more need for a cast:

next chapter:

```
SELECT min(chapter) FROM tab WHERE chapter > 20;
```

prev chapter:

```
SELECT max(chapter) FROM tab WHERE chapter < 20;
```